# UnauthorizedAccessException when calling FileInfo.Length

Tags: c#, android, .net, unity-game-engine

I do get reports via Crashlytics, that some of the Users of my Unity app (roughly 0.5%) get an UnauthorizedAccessException when I call `FileInfo.Length;`

the interesting part of the stacktrace is:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.Exception
UnauthorizedAccessException : Access to the path '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myCompany.myGreatGame/files/assets/myAsset.asset' is denied.
System.IO.__Error.WinIOError (System.IO.__Error)
System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length (System.IO.FileInfo)
```

The corresponding File (it's a different file for every report) was written (or is currently written) by the same application (possibly many sessions earlier). The call happens in a backgroundthread and there might be some writing going on at the same time. But according to the .net doc this property should be pre-cached (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length?view=netframework-2.0)

The whole code causing it is:

```
private static long DirSize(DirectoryInfo d) 
{
    long size = 0;
    FileInfo[] fileInfos = d.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos) 
    {      
        size += fileInfo.Length;
    }
    ...
```

Did anyone experience something similar and knows what might be causing it?

Comment: Is the problem definitely in C#? I ask because the error mentions java (which also has a UAE)

Comment: I believe it's C# - it always says java.lang.Exception in the stacktrace - also for all my other Exceptions that's probably Firebase/Crashlytics/Unity related. Also the methods before are from my C# code.

Comment: Please add the full code or at least tell has the value of `d` or better said which is the exact file you are trying to access? And well yes it might also be a problem that you try to write at the same time

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a very exotic error, and because of that, I have no evidence to back up my suggestions.

**Suggestion 1:**
User has installed Antivirus software - Those applications work sometimes like malware, locking files that are not used by the host program to test them (especially if they want to prevent malicious behavior). This would explain the rare nature of the error. I would try to see [permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456397/checking-file-folder-access-permission) of the file after the failed call of the Length method, this might give you (and possibly us) more insights.

**Suggestion 2:**
You cannot read length when the application is actively writing to this file in some circumstances. This should never happen but bugs happen even in OS. Possible path: Some application is writing to the File. The file is modified and metadata (including Lenght) is written, while it happens you are reading length from another thread, OS Locks the file from reading metadata (including Length), while metadata is written (probably for security reasons)

**Suggestion 3 (and most probable):**
Bad SD Card/Memory/CPU - Some random errors always can happen because you do not control the client's hardware. I would check if this 0.5% of errors are not from one User, or seemingly from multiple users but because of other issues with hardware, their unique ID resets (check for other data like phone model as this might also give you clues).

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely trying to access a file you don't have permissions to access.  There are certain files that even Administrator cannot access.

You could do a Try/Catch block to handle the exception.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076336/getting-unauthorizedaccessexception-while-counting-the-size-of-the-directory).

Comment: But the files are written by the same application earlier in a subfolder of Application.persistentDataPath which is androids ExternalFilesDir (see https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html)

Comment: How can the permissions vanish in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

If you read carefully [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.length?view=netframework-2.0) it clearly states that:

1. an I/O Error is thrown in case the Refresh fails
2. The FileInfo.Length Property is pre-cached only in a very precise list of cases (GetDirectories, GetFiles, GetFileSystemInfos, EnumerateDirectories, EnumerateFiles, EnumerateFileSystemInfos). The cached info should be refreshed by calling the Refresh() method.

Interpolating #1 and #2 you easily identify the problem: while you try to get that information, you have a file open with an exclusive lock, which gives you the error in #1. I would suggest approaching this implementing two different logics, one is the obvious try/catch block, but because that block (a) costs in performances and (b) doesn't solve the logical problem of knowing the file size, you also should cache those data yourself when you acquire the exclusive lock.

Put those in a static table in memory, a simple key/value (file/size), and check against it before to call FileInfo.Length(). Basically, when you acquire the lock you add the file/size value to the dictionary, and when you are done you remove it. This way you will never get the error again while being able to compute the directory size all the same.

~Pino